# AJAX Bug - How can I fix this?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I have some code that I have gone over at least 30 times by now, and it has plagued me for months (really). I have fixed as many errors as I see, but it simply doesn't work. I hope that any reader of this can find my mistake...

Ok, so the code is simply an ajax request on a mouseover effect that posts data to another page, in which the data is received. Please take a look:

Here is the ajax request:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#secretcoin").mouseover(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "achievements.php",
            data: {
                Home_Coin_Locator: "Yes"
            },
            error: errorAlert
        });
    });
});
```

So that is the request - and now here is the receiving page, achievements.php

```
$achieve4 = $_POST['Home_Coin_Locator'];
if ($achieve4 == 'Yes') {
    $awardSTRsql = "UPDATE Awards_Inv SET Home_Coin_Locator='Yes' WHERE Username = '$username'";
    mysql_query($awardSTRsql, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
    $updatestatsSTRsql = "UPDATE User_Info SET Coins = Coins + 120, Skill_Points = Skill_Points + 10, Awards = Awards + 1 WHERE Username = '$username'";
    mysql_query($updatestatsSTRsql, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
} else {}
```

I have reduced my code to small amounts, and checked it vigorously, but it still doesn't work...

by the way, $connection is simply my connection to the database, which I can guarantee is accurate. $username is the session username that is defined in code that I didn't provide, but I also know that the variable is accurate...

Please help me!

Comment: What doesn't work?  Are you getting an error?  "it simply doesn't work" is not very helpful

Comment: Be careful about constructing SQL queries like that; is there any chance $username could be set to `"'; DROP TABLE Awards_Inv;--"?

Comment: The reason that you can't solve it is because, you are not saying what's wrong

Comment: Keep in mind that the "receiver" of an AJAX call doesn't have access to the variables in the sender, so you'll need to make a new $connection in it.  Also, it would be really helpful if you'd tell us exactly what "it doesn't work" means.  Is it not calling the reciever, is the reciever failing, is the reciever returning data but the sender not receiving it correctly?  A good Firebug session will tell you all that.

Comment: Hey guys, there are no errors returned, but the data doesn't get updated to the database, so my code isn't working somewhere, as it is supposed to update the stats.

Comment: I don't see where you say you're using jQuery and that is a jQuery ajax function. Have you included the jQuery library?

Comment: Yes, it is there, I can show the code to you if you want, but I'm pretty sure it is correct,     <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>

Comment: The receiver site does have the same exact $connection variable in it

Comment: How is $username defined? You probably need to include the username value in the AJAX post so the receiving script can know which username to associate each action with.

Comment: Username is defined when the user logs in, it gets set as a $_SESSION variable, so it can be used in any of my php pages.

Comment: Try to track your code. You can chrome's developer tools to view request and response. You can also log your MySQL queries and step through your PHP code.

Comment: I don't have chrome on this computer, but I have it at home.

Comment: I use the source code viewer, and no error pop up there...so it doesn't find anything for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javascript seems to be correct to test the php file easier you should do this:

```
> $achieve4 = $_GET['Home_Coin_Locator']; if ($achieve4 == 'Yes') {
>     $awardSTRsql = "UPDATE Awards_Inv SET Home_Coin_Locator='Yes' WHERE Username = '$username'";
>     mysql_query($awardSTRsql, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
>     $updatestatsSTRsql = "UPDATE User_Info SET Coins = Coins + 120, Skill_Points = Skill_Points + 10, Awards = Awards + 1 WHERE Username =
> '$username'";
>     mysql_query($updatestatsSTRsql, $connection) or die(mysql_error()); } else {}
```

then go to /achievements.php?Home_Coin_Locator=Yes and see if there is any error.

Make sure you php error reporting is on so if there are any errors they will be displayed.

Comment: ok, but can you help me out with $_GET posts, I can never seem to understand why anyone would do it, couldn't someone just change the url so that the info would be different than what the developer would want it to be?